# libssl-1.0.0 and libcrypto-1.0.0 32-bit under Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, ssl

I need to run a quite old program under Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit that requires, among others:

- libssl-1.0.0 32-bit
- libcrypto-1.0.0 32-bit

I wasn't able to find them - perhaps I didn't look at right places.
I also tried to symlink the newer version to the required ones but it fails. Example:

> undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks

Where should I search for them?

Comment: You need to add 32-vit architechture.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.0 is unsupported for 4 years. If you really need such old and long obsolete libraries you need to download the source and compile it yourself - https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/

Comment: @Pilot6: the problem as pointed out by @Steffen Ullrich is the 32-bit package are not available anymore. I've already tried with `sudo apt install libssl???:i386` but I found nothing suitable.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: your should be an answer rather a comment, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.0.0 is unsupported for 4 years. If you really need such old and long obsolete libraries you need to download the source and compile it yourself - https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/.

Note also that running such an old and unsupported software stack might introduce security issues. And it might even be that the application no longer works: The world has moved to using TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 and OpenSSL 1.0.0. has no support for these. The best you can get is TLS 1.0.